# Expressions pour manifester sa faim

Tags: expressions, argot, registre-familier

Quelles expressions connaissez-vous pour indiquer que l'on a faim? 
Je suis aussi intéressé par les expressions familières ou d'argot.

Comment: Fermé pour éviter la prolifération de réponses. Merci de compléter le wiki communautaire pour en ajouter.

Comment: @Evpok Pourquoi ne pas simplement protéger la question au lieu de la fermer? Les questions fermées attirent moins de visiteurs (et de contributeurs), et protéger la question empêcherait les nouveaux venus moins avisés d'ajouter de nouvelles réponses. Les utilisateurs plus chevronnés devraient être capables de lire un commentaire demandant de seulement ajouter au CW et d'obtempérer.

Comment: Ça peut effectivement se faire. Essayons.

Answer (score 15):

En vrac et de niveaux de langues divers

- J'ai faim
- J'ai la dalle
- J'ai les crocs
- J'ai l'estomac dans les talons
- J'ai le ventre creux
- J'ai une faim de loup
- Je crève la dalle
- Je meurs de faim
- Mon ventre crie famine
- Je suis affamé(e)
- J'ai une faim dévorante
- Je boufferais/mangerais un bœuf/une girafe/un cheval/ (en salade)

Parmi des expressions plus anciennes et/ou imagées et qui ne sont (hélas !) plus utilisées aujourd'hui:

- mi-XVIIème

  - Affamé comme un chasseur
  - Mes boyaux crient vengeance
  - Il a toujours une aune de boyaux vide
  - La gueule me gagne
  - La gueule me rabâte
  - Le mousse lui est crue au gosier
  - Plaider avec le boulanger
  - Il semble à mon ventre que le diable ait emporté mes dents
- fin-XVIIème

  - Le soleil luit dans son ventre
  - Être affamé comme un jeune levron
- XIXème

  - Avoir une crampe au pylore
  - J'ai une faim, que je la vois courir
- XXème

  - Claquer du bec
  - Avoir la boîte à ragoût qui fait bravo