# Pourquoi le français utilise "avoir" dans "avoir faim" et "avoir soif"

Tags: verbes, histoire, linguistique

Je voudrais savoir pourquoi en français, "avoir" est utilisé dans les expressions "avoir faim" et "avoir soif".

Y a-t-il une raison historique ?

Si c'est le cas, pourrait-on me la faire connaitre ?

Comment: On l'utilise aussi avec "froid", "chaud", et "sommeil".

Comment: Here's [a worksheet I made to practice many of the most common ones](https://tdchristian-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/sawczak_tdchristian_ca/EbZ8dfFgS0hElRMpP-288wUBGt5DadNNbtlG6wMiFGk1PQ?e=X8rQZ5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On utilise très logiquement ***avoir*** avec ***faim*** et ***soif*** dans toutes les langues romanes, et c'est aussi le verbe que les langues germaniques utilisent quand elles se servent des mots qui traduisent chez elles ***faim*** et ***soif*** (exemple: *Ich **habe** **Hunger**/**Durst*** en allemand. Merci @njzk2 !)

En anglais, ***hungry*** (adjectif) ne signifie pas "faim" (***hunger*** : nom commun) et ***thirsty*** (adjectif) ne signifie pas "soif" (***thirst*** : nom commun).

On utilise bien le verbe **être** en français pour des adjectifs aux sens proches :

> Je **suis** affamé.
> Je **suis** assoiffé.

De manière similaire, on dit "**J'ai** sommeil" (mot-à-mot : *I have tiredness*) mais "**Je suis** fatigué" (*I'm tired*.)

Hmm, j'ai déjà répondu à peu près [la même chose](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11848/1109) il y a huit ans...

Comment: Parlant de langues germaniques, en allemand: "Ich habe Durst/Hunger" Lit.: J'ai soif/faim. (La forme avec adjectif existe aussi, voir: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55102/ich-habe-durst-vs-ich-bin-durstig-which-is-more-common)